# Location cache in android ICS?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

my understanding is that in gingerbread and lower, android kept a cache of 200 wifi location fixes and 50 cell location fixes. These were stored in cache.wifi and 
cache.cell files at /data/data/com.google.android.location/files, and rooted devices could view these locations using apps like [this.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.rrelmy.android.locationcachemap&hl=en)

However, those types of apps no longer work in ICS devices. Does this mean android no longer caches cell/wifi location fixes? Or does it simply mean nobody has been able to create
a similiar type of app for ICS or nobody can figure out where the cache is stored anymore?

Assuming there is a cache stored locally on the device, then when a network provided location is requested, is the location returned by android retrieved via the local cache or 
is it a fresh one from the network? How do I know if its new or from the cache?

Lastly, how much network data do network provided locations (with wifi radio enabled/on and data connectivity on) actually use?

Thanks,
Dom

Comment: Did you ever find out about where the location cache went to?